# X11 XM_NAME type is 'UTF-8' rather than STRING_UTF8

Tags: utf-8, x11, xlib, xorg, icccm

I'm looking at some X11 code that uses `XmbTextListToTextProperty` to set the `WM_NAME` property, with encoding style `XTextStyle`.

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XmbTextListToTextProperty.html suggests `XTextStyle` means the type/encoding of the property will depend on the current locale.

I'm not sure how to interpret http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.1.2.1 , it seems it allows the type of `WM_NAME` to be dependent of the current locale.

My current locale is 'en_US.UTF-8'. Everything I've seen so far suggests that the type of `WM_NAME` should be of type `STRING`, `COMPOUND_STRING` or `UTF8_STRING`.

However, `xprop` reports `UTF-8`, and `xwininfo` reports 'name in unsupported encoding UTF-8'. Checking the code, indeed it has support for `UTF8_STRING` but not `UTF-8`.

I'm at a loss as to where this `UTF-8` comes from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like besides the standard types `STRING`, `COMPOUND_STRING` and `UTF8_STRING` (the latter is an XFree86 extension), it is also acceptable to have any multibyte encoding.

When passing `XTextStyle` to `XmbTextListToTextProperty` will simply take the current encoding from the current locale. In the `en_US.UTF-8` locale, that would be `UTF-8`. To get the standardized (by XFree86) `UTF8_STRING` type for the property, we need to pass `XUTF8StringStyle` to `XmbTextListToTextProperty` instead of `XTextStyle`